# Is it possible to send an email via google apps without an ssl cert?

Tags: asp.net, email

I'm trying to send email via google apps from my asp.net app and am getting the following exception:

{"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at                              "}

My Web.config has the following values (sorry I couldn't get the XML to display):

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="user@domain.com"
              deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
                     port="587"
                     userName="user@domain.com"
                     password="password"
                     enableSsl="true"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I'm thinking that this is due to my not having an SSL cert but I'm not sure.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can add add XML by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working this way with one of our gmail account (code is simplified):

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "smtp.gmail.com");
 client.EnableSsl = true;
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);
 client.Send(mail); // mail is of type System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
```

You could try to send an email with this code and your configuration just to see if you receive the same error message.

Comment: The issue was that I was using the NetworkCredential ctor overload which accepts a domain.  When I removed this everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine; I use the exact same configuration successfully.

You may have a firewall issue.